# API calls don't work in Safari due to some SSL rule

Tags: nginx, next.js, safari, cloudflare, fastify

I have an application in Full Stack format and I am facing some problems to perform the communication between the front end and the backend, the problem is that these errors are occurring exclusively in Safari.

The framework consists of a backend built on Node.js using the Fastify library, located on myapp_api.example.com and a frontend built on Next.js located on myapp.example.com

I use Cloudflare to organize my DNS structure and to make sure that the problem was not SSL, I changed the way we performed encryption from flexible to strict, which did not solve the problem.

I use Nginx to perform the reverse proxy.

Remember: The error is happening exclusively in Safari and the application works normally in other browsers
I'm getting the following error in the console when performing queries through Safari:

```
An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myapp_api.example.com/sessions due to access control checks.

Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

Can you help me or has anyone been through something similar?